# Design Issue - decoding json to specific object class or generic JsonEntity

Tags: android, json, converters, decode

I'm working at an Android application that receives some JSON objects through HTTP. Then i store received data to DB. Data received through http differs from data stored in database, so i have 2 layers - transport layer, with transport objects, and DB layer with domain object. There are converters that transform information from TO to DO, and otherway.

I would like to know which of following alternatives are better:

1. decode received data to Specific Transport Object (with gson) - FooTO, then convert into FooDO with FooConvertor, and the store FooDO into DB.

   ```
                        gson                   FooConvertor           DAO
   ```

   http content(string) ------>   **FooTO**   ---------------> FooDO --------> Database
2. decode received data to generic JsonEntity, then convert information with FooConvertor to FooDO, and the store FooDO into DB.

   ```
                        gson                   FooConvertor           DAO
   ```

   http content(string) ------> **JSONEntity** --------------> FooDO --------> Database

An important aspect is that i have no control over structure of json object received via http, its structure may change any time, so i want to minimize change impact in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with the `GSON` library usage as it is more structured and the classes created during the fetching of JSON can be reused for storing the same data in the DB